# Is there an alternative to the "sync" option of mount when mounting an external USB HDD?

Tags: usb, mount, sync

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 laptop that I connect to a docking hub with an external usb hard drive also attached to the hub. If I mount my external usb hard drive with sync then I get transfer speeds of approximately 100MiB/s from the drive and 60 KiB/s to the drive:

```
user@computer:~$ sudo mount -o rw,sync /dev/sdb2 /mnt/usb_disk
user@computer:~$ date; pv ~/10Mfile > /mnt/usb_disk/10Mfile; sudo umount /mnt/usb_disk; date
Thu Sep 26 14:20:35 CDT 2019
10.0MiB 0:03:00 [56.8KiB/s] [=====================================================================================>] 100%            
Thu Sep 26 14:23:36 CDT 2019
user@computer:~$
```

If I mount the external usb hard drive without sync then I get transfer speeds of approximately 100MiB/s both to and from the drive:

```
user@computer:~$ sudo mount -o rw /dev/sdb2 /mnt/usb_disk
user@computer:~$ date; pv ~/1Gfile > /mnt/usb_disk/1Gfile; sudo umount /mnt/usb_disk; date
Thu Sep 26 14:14:35 CDT 2019
1.00GiB 0:00:09 [ 109MiB/s] [=====================================================================================>] 100%
Thu Sep 26 14:14:49 CDT 2019
user@computer:~$
```

The umount takes about 5 seconds without sync, but clearly the write speed increase is not just due to buffering.

The drive is formatted as ntfs. I would prefer to keep it that way for ease of compatibility with Windows, but I would also like to know if re-formatting the drive as ext4 (or anything else) will solve the write speed problem.

I have tried every usb port on the docking station and the laptop. The speeds are consistent.

I would prefer not to give up the sync option, since the drive is connected to a docking station and sometimes I have to just close up the laptop in a hurry and go. Is there some way I can keep the safety of sync, but improve the write speed to the drive?